That the train is delayed may well be

That the train is delayed may well be.

Is this sentence grammatical or idiomatic?
If so, the 'to be' means exists? There is no complement.

If you are simply trying to say the train may be delayed, then say exactly that.  The train may be delayed.

It is grammatical, but that structure is pretty much limited to argumentative contexts in a rejoinder:

That the train is delayed may very well be the case, but ...
That the train is delayed may well be, but...

Otherwise it is not idiomatic in contemporary English. The structure native speakers would choose (if they're going to use "well") is:

It may well be (that) the train is delayed.

if people are on the platform and wondering if the train has been cancelled, encountered debris on the tracks, struck a car at a road crossing, has been halted because of "police activity", has had to slow down because of slippery rails, left the station late because of staffing issues, whatever. (These are actual reasons why our local trains are often late, BTW.)
Bare uncomplemented be there could be paraphrased as "is a fact", "is the reality", "is the case".
When proposing such assertion as an explanation, the speaker is presenting it as a reasonable supposition.  In a rejoinder, "may well be" is concessive.

Do we need 'that' in the sentence 'It may well be that the train is delayed.'?

that is optional. I'll edit.

I would tend to find this unacceptable grammar. As you note, the use of "be" without complement is limited to senses meaning "exist":  "I think therefore I am." But the meaning of the content clause doesn't identify a "thing" that could exist or not exist. So the grammar is incongruous and in my judgement, it is incongruous to the extent that it is ungrammatical.
There are plenty of grammatically correct ways to express this.  Use one of those.  "The train may well be delayed.
